# Как скрыть приложение, если нажимаешь на кнопку закрыть на окне?

Tags: c++, windows

начал изучать программирование на windows. и вот у меня есть проблема. я вообще не знаю правильно ли я всё делаю. И вот есть ещё проблема в том, что окно как будто уничтожается, а не скрывается. Я думал что если добавить в WM_DESTROY, команду скрыть окно, то так и будет, но это уничтожает иконку в трее. Вот код.

```
// test.cpp : Определяет точку входа для приложения.
//
//#pragma comment(lib, "Shell32.lib")

#include "framework.h"
#include "test.h"
#include <Shellapi.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
#define IDM_SHOW_PROGRAM    0
#define IDM_EXIT_PROGRAM    1

// Глобальные переменные:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // текущий экземпляр
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // Текст строки заголовка
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // имя класса главного окна
NOTIFYICONDATAA Icon = { 0 };



// Отправить объявления функций, включенных в этот модуль кода:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
VOID                initShellIcon( HWND hwnd );

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Разместите код здесь.

    // Инициализация глобальных строк
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_TEST, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Выполнить инициализацию приложения:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_TEST));

    MSG msg;

    // Цикл основного сообщения:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  ФУНКЦИЯ: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  ЦЕЛЬ: Регистрирует класс окна.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_TEST));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_TEST);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   ФУНКЦИЯ: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   ЦЕЛЬ: Сохраняет маркер экземпляра и создает главное окно
//
//   КОММЕНТАРИИ:
//
//        В этой функции маркер экземпляра сохраняется в глобальной переменной, а также
//        создается и выводится главное окно программы.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Сохранить маркер экземпляра в глобальной переменной

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   initShellIcon(hWnd);

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);


   return TRUE;
}

//
//  ФУНКЦИЯ: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  ЦЕЛЬ: Обрабатывает сообщения в главном окне.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - обработать меню приложения
//  WM_PAINT    - Отрисовка главного окна
//  WM_DESTROY  - отправить сообщение о выходе и вернуться
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_USER:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(lParam);
            switch (wmId) {
            case WM_RBUTTONUP:
            {
                POINT pt;
                GetCursorPos(&pt);

                HMENU hMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
                AppendMenuA(hMenu, MF_ENABLED | MF_STRING, IDM_SHOW_PROGRAM, "&Показать окно");
                AppendMenuA(hMenu, MF_ENABLED | MF_STRING, IDM_EXIT_PROGRAM, "&Выход");
                TrackPopupMenu(hMenu, TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, pt.x, pt.y, 0, hWnd, NULL);
                DestroyMenu(hMenu);
            }
                break;
            }
        }
        break;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Разобрать выбор в меню:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_SHOW_PROGRAM:
                ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
                break;
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);

                break;
            case IDM_EXIT_PROGRAM:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Добавьте сюда любой код прорисовки, использующий HDC...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);

        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Обработчик сообщений для окна "О программе".
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}

VOID initShellIcon( HWND hwnd ) {
    Icon.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATAA);
    Icon.hWnd = hwnd;
    Icon.uFlags = NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_ICON;
    Icon.uVersion = NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4;
    Icon.uCallbackMessage = WM_USER;
    Icon.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_SHIELD);
    Shell_NotifyIconA(NIM_ADD, &Icon);

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> case WM_DESTROY:
>    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
> ```

Уничтоженное окно нельзя скрыть... как и отменить уничтожение. Обрабатывайте вместо него сообщение [WM_CLOSE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-close). По умолчанию его обработчик просто уничтожает окно. Это вызывает ваш код, но слишком поздно. Вы можете переопределить эту логику, вызывая свой код и **не** передавая управление DefWindowProc, тогда оно не будет уничтожаться.

Comment: Спасибо.!!!!!!!